# Subtract max from elements of Boost C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays, numpy, boost

I have a Boost.Numpy array `foo` of length `x`, e.g. `foo = [-0.7, -0.9, -0.6]`. I would like to subtract the max value from each element, resulting in `foo = [-0.1, -0.3, 0.0]`. Trying `boost::range::max_element(foo)` I get `error: no matching function for call to 'max_element'`. So I've done the following hack to get the max value,

```
// a bunch of hacky stuff b/c std algorithms don't work well w/ boost arrays
Py_intptr_t const *foo_stride = foo.get_strides();
char const *begin_foo = foo.get_data();
char const *end_foo = foo + foo_stride[0]*x;
double foo_max = *std::max_element(begin_foo, end_foo);
```

And then I tried using a lambda for subtracting the max:

```
std::for_each(begin_foo, end_foo, [](double& d) {d-=foo_max;});
```

but to no avail: `error: no matching function for call to object of type` pointing to the capture `[]`; trying `[&]` and `[=]` didn't work either. So I now have a for loop:

```
for (auto i=0; i<x; ++i) {foo[ii] -= foo_max;}
```

But this doesn't work as expected. `foo_max` is actually a char that is cast to double in the earlier assignment. So the earlier hack to find the max value is broken. Please help. I'm aware of the Boost.Numpy [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/reference/ndarray.html), [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/tutorial/ndarray.html), and [examples](https://github.com/boostorg/python/blob/master/example/numpy/ndarray.cpp), and they're rather poor.

Comment: It is not your day.:)

Comment: `char const *begin_foo` -- should probably cast those to `double const*` if you want to read doubles and not signed bytes....

Comment: Some further thoughts - there's [`numpy.amax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html). Boost python lets us [import modules](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/embedding/boost_python_import_hpp.html), represented as `object`. We can grab attributes (functions are attributes of a module) and store them in an `object` instance, and we can use `operator()` on those objects to call the functions they represent. So you could get an object to represent `numpy.amax` and use that to get the maximum value. (cont...)

Comment: Furthermore, `boost::python::numpy::ndarray` derives from `boost::python::object`. That means you have all the operators available, and they should work just like they do in Python. Say you stored the `numpy.amax` function in `bp::object np_amax;`, and we have our `bpn::ndarray foo`, I assume you can do something like `foo -= np_amax(foo);` Damn, I'll have to upgrade my Boost, so I can answer your questions properly and not just speculate :D

Comment: One further thought - if you continue with your approach using pointers, you should verify that `foo_stride[0] == sizeof(double)` (or whatever may be the appropriate element type). In most cases this would be true, but in case it's not, you would probably need to iterate by hand.

Comment: Thank you for the tips @DanMašek! I tried `boost::python::object numpy = bpy::import("numpy");` and then `double Y_left_max = numpy.amax(foo);`, but this won't build b/c `error: no member named 'amax' in 'boost::python::api::object'`.

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain Oh, it wouldn't be `numpy.amax(foo)`; You need to use the `attr` method of `object` to get the function first: `bp::object np_amax = numpy.attr("amax");` (keep in mind that here we get the module from the interpreter at runtime -- it could really be any valid python module named `numpy`, so the compiler has no chance to know there is some method named `amax` as you tried to do.)

Comment: @DanMašek ah of course, now it's working, thank you.

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain No problem :) Feel free to write it up. You could cache the function object for the lifetime of the interpreter, so you avoid having to extract it every time. There's going to be some overhead in invoking the function through the interpreter, but for decent sized array this should be negligible. On the other hand, the numpy interpretation should be quite optimized, and AFAICT it should work for any shape of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per comments from [@Dan Mašek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek):

```
// Load the numpy.amax module
bpy::object numpy = bpy::import("numpy");
bpy::object numpy_amax = numpy.attr("amax");
auto foo_max = numpy_amax(foo);
for (auto i=0; i<x; ++i) {foo[i] -= foo_max;}
```